# Getting `illegal pointer` error when using AddFriend from ROOT(cern)

Tags: c++, pointers, tree, root-framework

**Aim;**
I wish to compare the contents of two [ROOT](https://root.cern.ch/drupal/) [TTree](https://root.cern.ch/root/html/TTree.html) objects that have identical structure (but not identical contents obviously). The best way to do this seems to be using [AddFriend](https://root.cern.ch/root/html/TTree.html#TTree:AddFriend).

**Problem;**
I am getting this error message;

```
Error: illegal pointer to class object t3 0x0 1681  makeFriends.C:6:
*** Interpreter error recovered ***
```

**What I've tried so far;**
After running the example at the bottom of [this page](ftp://root.cern.ch/root/doc/ROOTUsersGuideHTML/ch12s16.html) successfully I decided to reduce it down to just the reading and friend adding section, as I had already created `tree3.root` and `tree3f.root` in the first run. So I had a file called tree3.C containing;

```
// Function to read the two files and add the friend
void tree3r()         {
  TFile *f = new TFile("tree3.root");
  TTree *t3 = (TTree*)f->Get("t3");
  // Add the second tree to the first tree as a friend
  t3->AddFriend("t3f","tree3f.root");
  // Draw pz which is in the first tree and use pt 
  // in the condition. pt is in the friend tree.
  //t3->Draw("pz","pt>5");
}
```

This worked as expected, when loaded (`root[] .L tree3.C`) and run (`root[] tree3r()`) from the root prompt.

So I put a copy in a folder containing both of my root files, `plainMaskOutput.root` and `DNMaskOutput.root`, and changed strings in the copy to match the names of my files. So I have;

```
// Function to read the two files and add the friend
void tree3r()         {
TFile *f = new TFile("plainMaskOutput.root");
TTree *t3 = (TTree*)f->Get("t3");
   // Add the second tree to the first tree as a friend
t3->AddFriend("t3f","DNMaskOutput.root");
   // Draw pz which is in the first tree and use pt 
   // in the condition. pt is in the friend tree.
//t3->Draw("pz","pt>5");
}
```

Which gives the error above. I dont understand why these things are behaving diffrently? Why can't they just be friends?

Comment: This is so not `C`......`new`??? in `C`???

Comment: @SouravGhosh sorry, it was recommended and I clicked without thinking

Comment: I retagged with `C++`.

Comment: is there a way to check the result? for example, that your method `Get` didn't return `nullptr`.

Comment: @varnie I will look into that and get back to you

Comment: @varnie yes you right, its a null pointer, the `Get` is not working. (and in the version that does work it is not a null pointer)  Any idea why?

Comment: Does this https://root.cern.ch/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=12407 help you? Looks like they're discussing exactly the same issue. Try adding `f->ls();` in above and recheck. Also this link https://root.cern.ch/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=12180 worth checking it.

Comment: be vary wary of [C style casts](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) they may not do what you expect them to do. Rather use the safer (and more explicit) [`static_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) whenever possible instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that `TFile`s method `Get` might return null, indicating the failure. You were not taking that into account. Why does it return null in your case?

According to the link I provided in the comments (https://root.cern.ch/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=12407) it is because your file doesn't contain a tree having a name you provided.

It will be better to add an explicit check of the returned value from `Get`. if the file gets changed later, your program will start to crash again.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `plainMaskOutput.root` is a file name and the string inside the `Get()` parenthesis is the tree name. The file called `plainMaskOutput.root` did not contain a tree by the name `t3` it contained one by the name `HitsTree`. So the line should have been;

```
TTree *foo = (TTree*)f->Get("HitsTree");
```

Similarly, the add friend command needed to have the name of the tree stored in `DNMaskOutput.root`, but as they have the same name it should be [aliased](ftp://root.cern.ch/root/doc/ROOTUsersGuideHTML/ch12s16.html);

```
foo->AddFriend("DNHitsTree = HitsTree","DNMaskOutput.root");
```

This is just the problem I was having this time, it may not always be the problem associated with this error. I am not knowledgeable enough in this area to say what other problems are possible.

Comment: Credit goes to @varnie for giving links that solved this.